# Moscapsule in Swift 3, disconnects when iPhone screen is turned off

Tags: ios, swift3, mqtt

I am using Moscapsule library for publish/subscribe on broker in my iOS app.
Application is working fine until iPhone screen is turned off.
When iPhone screen is turned off(automatically or manually), MQTT connection disconnects.

I am not sure if iOS is doing so, or is it related to keepAlive parameter in MQTT Config.

Can I stop the MQTT disconnect, when device screen is turned off.

Thanks